# Problem when attempting to loop AVPlayer (userCapturedVideo) seamlessly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I have been looking around for a while on how to correctly accomplish this. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026583/avplayerlooper-black-flash-after-each-iteration) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285826/looping-avplayer-seamlessly). And have used the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285826/looping-avplayer-seamlessly), to try and accomplish this however for me the recorded video does not ever even begin to loop. The first frame shows up but does not play the video, thus I am wondering what's wrong.

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
    if (error != nil) {
        print("Error recording movie11: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        isSettingThumbnail = false

        let videoRecorded = outputURL! as URL
        playRecordedVideo(video: videoRecorded)

        if !captureSession.isRunning {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                self.startRunningCaptureSession()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function used in the above method is bellow.

```
    func playRecordedVideo(video: URL) {
    thumbImage = nil
    playerQueue = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: video))

    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: playerQueue)
    playerLayer.frame = (camBaseLayer?.bounds)!
    playerLayer?.layoutIfNeeded()
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.isHidden = false

    camBaseLayer?.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, above: previewLayer)

    playerItem1 = AVPlayerItem(url: video)

    playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: playerQueue, templateItem: playerItem1)
    self.playerQueue?.play()
}
```

I have attempted the following in the function above:

```
        var num = 0
    if num == 0 {
        self.playerQueue?.play()
        num+=1
    } else {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.playerQueue.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.playerQueue.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
                self.playerQueue.play()
            }
        })

    }
```

This however just causes the video to not even play when it comes up.

The goal is to prevent the "gap" you see when the video is looped

**Update**:

Ok so actually the variable num should be outside of the function which then would make the NS code run but that ends up freezing the view like it did before.

**Update 2:**

I have not been able to find a solution to this as of yet. But what is for certain is that

```
`            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.playerQueue.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.playerQueue.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
                    self.playerQueue.play()
                }
            })
```

`
Causes the video to not even loop. Any reason as to why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same thing a few years back using this piece of code:

```
var player: AVPlayer!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

private func playVideo(name: String) {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType:"mp4") else { return }
    player = AVPlayer(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path) as URL)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    self.playerLayer.frame = SOME_BOUNDS
    self.player!.play()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
}

@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    print("Video Finished")
    self.playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    playVideo(name: "SOME_NAME")
}
```

Hope this points you to your desired functionality

Comment: From my implementation it stiull has teh blip

Comment: But i think its just because our asset times are different. So I guess it may work for others